# How to get all not null columns in a table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, constraints, notnull

I have a requirement to find all not-null columns in a table. For example, my table is the below one

[image]

Lets say, Column1, Column2 and Column3 have not-null constraints and Column4, Column5 and Column6 are of nullable types. Is there any query in Oracle that list the column names that are of not-null types, ie I need to get the column names Column1, Column2 and Column3.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

```
Column1
Column2
Column3
```

I know there should be a simple way to achieve this, but am new to Oracle. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can query the `all_tab_columns` table:

```
select column_name
from all_tab_columns
where table_name = 'TABLE1'
and nullable = 'N';
```

Answer (score 3):

> I know there should be a simple way to achieve this, but am new to Oracle.

Well, [online documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/REFRN/refrn20277.htm#REFRN20277) is exactly what you need to look into.

Depending on the **privilege**, you need to look into **[DBA|USER|ALL]_TAB_COLUMNS**.

```
ALL_TAB_COLUMNS

Column      Datatype        Description
NULLABLE    VARCHAR2(1)     Indicates whether a column allows NULLs. 
                            The value is N if there is a NOT NULL constraint
                            on the column or if the column is part of a PRIMARY KEY. 
                            The constraint should be in an ENABLE VALIDATE state.
```

So, per the documentation, you need to use the **filter**:

```
NULLABLE = 'N'
```